# getting a more specific array from an array - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have this array:

```
[[#<Ticket:0x007f993e368538 id: 400, attendee_id: 436, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 10>,
  #<Ticket:0x007f993e3683f8 id: 401, attendee_id: 437, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 10>],
 [#<Ticket:0x007f993e56af20 id: 407, attendee_id: 443, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 11>,
  #<Ticket:0x007f993e56ade0 id: 408, attendee_id: 444, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 11>,
  #<Ticket:0x007f993e56aca0 id: 409, attendee_id: 445, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 11>],
 [#<Ticket:0x007f993dc7db60 id: 415, attendee_id: 451, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 12>,
  #<Ticket:0x007f993dc7da20 id: 416, attendee_id: 452, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 12>,
  #<Ticket:0x007f993dc7d8e0 id: 417, attendee_id: 453, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 12>,
  #<Ticket:0x007f993dc7d7a0 id: 418, attendee_id: 454, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 12>,
  #<Ticket:0x007f993dc7d660 id: 419, attendee_id: 455, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 12>],
 [#<Ticket:0x007f993dde8c98 id: 423, attendee_id: 459, ticket_type_id: 33, purchase_id: 13>,
  #<Ticket:0x007f993dde8ae0 id: 424, attendee_id: 460, ticket_type_id: 33, purchase_id: 13>,
  #<Ticket:0x007f993dde89a0 id: 425, attendee_id: 461, ticket_type_id: 33, purchase_id: 13>]]
```

I got it with this code: `event.purchases.collect(&:tickets)`

Now that I have that array I want to get an array of just the ticket_type_id value. so it should look like this `[29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 33, 33, 33]`

Hopefully that is enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in another related question of yours, if you add an association in `Event`:

```
has_many :tickets, through: :purchases
```

It would look cleaner to just get `event.tickets` which are all the tickets of purchases belonging to this event.

Else, `map` is the solution as Ursus replied.

Comment: Thanks for all the help this is a part of a bigger problem. I posted another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017308/getting-total-count-of-tickets-sold-for-a-table-rails I'd love your help on it Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
event.purchases.flat_map(&:tickets).map(&:ticket_type_id)
```

`map` is like `collect`

But it's possible do everything in SQL that is often better. Something like this should work

```
Ticket.joins(:purchase).where(purchases: { event_id: event.id }).pluck(:ticket_type_id)
```

Comment: using `pluck` instead of `select` (if it is Rails) allows you get an array without model creating (it's faster and consuming less memory)

Comment: @Ursus Thank you for the help! This is a part of a bigger problem I'd love your help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017308/getting-total-count-of-tickets-sold-for-a-table-rails Thanks man