# Getting total count of tickets sold for a table. Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Okay. I'm trying to fill a table with data of how many tickets have been sold for each ticket type.

[image]

So, An `event` has many `tickets` and a ticket has a `ticket_type`. I need to get a total count of tickets sold for each ticket type. In the image above you can see that I'm getting the wrong data for quantity sold.

### MODALS:

## EVENT:

```
has_many :ticket_types, dependent: :destroy
has_many :purchases, dependent: :destroy
has_many :tickets, through: :purchases
```

## TICKET:

```
belongs_to :ticket_type
belongs_to :purchase
```

## TICKET_TYPE:

```
belongs_to :event
```

Here is the table loop:

```
  <% event.ticket_types.each do |ticket_type| %>
    <tr class=tickets-sold-modal__data>
      <td><%= ticket_type.name %></td>
      <td>$<%= ticket_type.amount.to_i %></td>
      <td><%= event.ticket_type_purchases %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

In this iteration I'm calling `event.ticket_type_purchases` which is this method:

```
 def ticket_type_purchases
  event.tickets.group(:ticket_type_id).count
 end
```

That is returning the value in the screen shot for quantity sold. With the given information how can I collect the `TOTAL TICKETS SOLD FOR EACH TICKET TYPE` and display that on the screen?

Comment: I understand I'll delete that ASAP. I don't know if it's critical to the answer. just a helper.

Comment: No Problem Cary. I'll add it back. It may help some folks in the future, who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your view code to this:

```
<tr class=tickets-sold-modal__data>
  <td><%= ticket_type.name %></td>
  <td>$<%= ticket_type.amount.to_i %></td>
  <td><%= event.ticket_type_purchases[ticket_type.id] || 0 %></td>
</tr>
```

But optimize the above code to store output of event.ticket_type_purchases in a variable, so that the database calls are not made multiple times.

Comment: MAN! Thank You SOO much! I owe you a beer!